# How to install GeForce Go 7400 driver to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, nvidia-geforce

I have rather old Sony laptop - VGN-FE890. It uses GeForce Go 7400 video card and for this card there is no driver neither in windows itself nor at NVidia site. I had this problem when I were using preview version of Windows 8 and it was easily solved by downloading driver for Vista/Windows7 version 179.48. But now it doesn't want to install.

There is the screencast where this problem get solved by exactly the same way and on release version on Windows 8 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JCfHAGS624). But it doesn't work for me.

**UPD:** When I run setup I'm getting the following error:
The NVIDIA Setup program could not locate any drivers that are compatible with your current hardware. Setup will now exit.

I think this should be solvable. After all, it was working in preview versions.

Comment: Please provide more details on how its "not working" saying it doesn't work doesn't describe the problem.

Comment: Updated. The error is very boring: "The NVIDIA Setup program could not locate any drivers that are compatible with your current hardware. Setup will now exit."

Comment: Do they have manual setups that you can choose yourself with your own knowledge of your devices?

Comment: No, they don't. After unpacking this NVidia package I got the directory C:\NVIDIA\WinVista\179.48\IS with setup files. Display drivers are (most likely) in Display subfolder of it. It has a plenty of .inf files. I tried to update driver with some of them. After selecting inf file I get a list of around 60 drivers with name 7400 w/o apparent difference in names. Tried several - all are incompatible.

Comment: try pnputil -a <name.inf> to add the driver to Windows Driver store. Now let Windows search for a driver.

Comment: @magicandre1981, there are around 20 .inf files there. Which one should I add? All of them?

Comment: Well, all inf files were added successfully, but automatic driver search anyway offers only Microsoft Basic Display Adapter.

Comment: Your only option it seems is to use the generic drivers published by Microsoft.

Comment: what happens when you try to install the INF with device manager (http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9695-driver-install-device-manager-windows-8-a.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved. Take drivers from here: 
http://laptopvideo2go.com/drivers/vista/180.70/disclaimer

Download and unpack archive, download and replace nv_disp.inf file and then run setup.

Thanks to all of your and especially for NVidia support guys from their forum:
https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/527390/geforce-drivers/drivers-for-geforce-go-7400-in-sony-vaio-

Comment: This worked for my Sony Vaio VGN-SZ440 with new Windows 8 Pro install. Sony, Microsoft and Nvidia all let me down, but this site/answer solved my screen resolution problem. Thanks XOR!

Answer (score 0):

The video device is likley specific to the Sony build.  See this often with Dell. This is why installer fails as it checks some hardware item and sees it is not nVidia built.  If no Sony support, you may need to find specific files from a similar card.

As noted by @Ariane, there may be a manual install but it will likley need some experiemnting.

Also worth checking the Microsoft [Windows 8 hardware compatibility site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/Home?Language=en-US)

Comment: Already wrote to Sony, but don't expect any good from them. AFAIK their support is far from being friendly.